# When setting user permissions to open up a particular form for a particular user I am getting a Runtime error from the DLookup statement

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am trying to restrict the availability of a form to be opened by a user. the following code picks up on the correct user access type and the correct form name, however i am getting the runtime error 2471. I would appreciate some help here as i cannot see what is wrong?

The error statement in this case is: Run-Time error '2471': The expression you entered as a query parameter produced this error: 'Stock'. When i go to debug it brings me to the DLookup and i cannot see what is wrong.

Watch expression:Watch :   : "Employeeaccesstype =" & cable & " " & "AND FormName=" & thisform : "Employeeaccesstype =0 AND FormName=Stock" : String : Form_Stock.Form_Load

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim cable As String
cable = TempVars("AccessType")
Dim thisform As String
thisform = Me.Form.Name
If DLookup("Hasaccess", "tblemployeeaccess", "Employeeaccesstype =" & cable & " " & "AND FormName=" & thisform) = False Then
DoCmd.Close
MsgBox "You Do Not Have Access"
End If
End Sub
```

All help will be most appreciated as i am on a deadline to finish this

Answer (score 0):

If your fields `Employeeaccesstype` and `FormName` are text, then the values in the Dlookup need to be wrapped in single quotes. Additionally, you should cater for the possibility that the record doesn't exist in the table (returning a Null value from the DLookup):

```
If Nz(DLookup("Hasaccess", "tblemployeeaccess", "Employeeaccesstype ='" & cable & "' AND FormName='" & thisform & "'"),False) = False Then
```

You should also consider not actually allowing them to open the form in the first place.

Regards,

Comment: Applecore I added this in but i still get the same error. It seems to have issue with thisform rather than anything else as

Comment: Use `Debug.Print` in this procedure to get the values of `cable` and `thisform`, and then use `DLookup` in the immediate window with these values hardcoded in rather than concatenated to see what is being looked up.

Comment: Applecore I haven't used debug.print before can you give me an example of how to use it in this context please

Comment: Before the `DLookup`, just `Debug.Print cable` and `Debug.Print thisform` Then in the Immediate Window (accessed through Ctl-G), `?DLookup("Hasaccess","tblemployeeaccess","Employeeaccesstype='cable' AND FormName='formname'")`.

Comment: Applecore I tried this and cable comes up with 3 and this form with Stock which is as it should be. when using the immediate window  I get the following: The expression you entered as a query parameter produced this error: The object doesn't contain the automation object "Stock".

Comment: What datatype is the field `cable`? And can you please paste the full `DLookup` that you are using in the immediate window.

Comment: Nz(DLookup("Hasaccess", "tblemployeeaccess", "Employeeaccesstype =" & 3 & " " & "AND FormName= Stock"), False) = False  and cable is the return from the records set stored in tempvars

Comment: As I said in my original answer, you need to wrap any text strings in single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I changed tack here and went for a different approach. I  created a new table to hold user login details and a query to join details on tables and referenced that on the Dlookup rather than trying to reference the login form through a variable. Witth those changes made i changed the DLookup to

```
If DLookup("Hasaccess", "AccessQuery", "HasAccess =false and Formname = 'Part' ") = 
False Then
DoCmd.Close
MsgBox "You Do Not Have Access"

End If
```

This is now working correctly. Many thanks o Applecore for the assistance with this problem